How to add engine evaluation to a pgn file?
I have pgn file of thousands of game, with the clock only, every move have comment like this, this is a pgn file downloaded from lichess:
{[%clk 0:10:00]}
I need to add engine eval to every move like this
{[%eval 0.82] [%clk 0:10:00]}
the reason is, when browsing the pgn file with scid, I want the eval bar to show it.

You can use the [] syntax in the PGN spec and add the eval key like this:
1. e4 {[%eval +0.23]} e5 {[%eval +0.16]} 2. Nf3 {[%eval +0.30]} Nc6 {[%eval +0.11]}
3. Bb5 {[%eval +0.35]} a6 {[%eval -0.17]} 4. Ba4 {[%eval +0.40]} Nf6 {[%eval +0.03]}
5. O-O {[%eval +0.50]} Be7 {[%eval +0.01]} 6. Re1 {[%eval +0.54]} b5 {[%eval +0.13]}
7. Bb3 {[%eval +0.59]} d6 {[%eval +0.08]} 8. c3 {[%eval +0.45]} O-O {[%eval +0.14]}
9. h3 {[%eval +0.46]} Nb8 {[%eval +0.16]} 10. d4 {[%eval +0.52]} Nbd7 {[%eval +0.12]}

But the application reading this pgn would have to know about the "eval" keyword here to parse it correctly.
Similar question was answered here:
What is %eval syntax in PGN

Take a Chess GUI like Arena, Chessbase GUI or Shredder Chess, load your PGN and start an Automatic Analysis with a chess engine, this will add comments from the engine. There are several options you can chose from before running this analysis.
